# how to add imageview to layer with delay in java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

Thread and sleep and Handler were not Helpful.
this is my code.

```
while(true){
        ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
        image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(80,60));
        image.setMaxHeight(80);
        image.setMaxWidth(50);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.missile);


        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, -800.0f);          //  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
        animation.setDuration(700);   
        animation.setFillAfter(true); 
        image.startAnimation(animation);
        LinearLayout missile_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.missile_layout);
        missile_layout.addView(image,0);
    }
```

Comment: if post delayed is not what you need - try to explain what kind of delay do you need and for what?

Comment: I want to add imageviews one by one with delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    // flag that should be set true if handler should stop
 boolean mStopHandler = false;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  // load the layout
  setContentView(R.layout.filters);
  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    addView();
    if (!mStopHandler) {
     mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
   }
  };

  // start it with:
  mHandler.post(runnable);
 }






 public void addView() {
  ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
  image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(80, 60));
  image.setMaxHeight(80);
  image.setMaxWidth(50);
  image.setImageResource(R.drawable.missile);


  TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0 f, 0.0 f, 10.0 f, -800.0 f); //  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
  animation.setDuration(700);
  animation.setFillAfter(true);
  image.startAnimation(animation);
  LinearLayout missile_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.missile_layout);
  missile_layout.addView(image, 0);
 }
```

Comment: thanks.but not work.all of imageviews adding together.

Comment: do you want to add them one  by one?

Comment: excuse me.what is the **mHandler**?

Comment: just an object of the Handler

Comment: fine thanks.solved.but first Y_location of imageviews decrease gradually!  in other word imageviews moves start point approaching to top of screen

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
while(true){
        ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
        image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(80,60));
        image.setMaxHeight(80);
        image.setMaxWidth(50);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.missile);


        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, -800.0f);          //  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
        animation.setDuration(700);   
        animation.setFillAfter(true); 
        image.startAnimation(animation);
        LinearLayout missile_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.missile_layout);

    missile_layout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            missile_layout.addView(image,0);
        }
    }, 5000
);
}
```

Comment: thanks.but not work.all of imageviews adding together.